# How to view list of changes to fetch from upstream/origin, or changes to push to upstream/origin

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I'm trying to get a feel for how to do certain things in TortoiseGit that are pretty intuitive in TortoiseHG.

TortoiseHG has the [Workbench](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/workbench.html) which basically is my central tool to sync the local repository with remote ones: upstreams and origin.

It is easy to see what changes I'm missing locally (so I need to fetch them) or remotely (so I need to push them).

What is similar functionality in TortoiseGit?

- How can I see a list of changes from a remote origin or upstream that I want to fetch locally?
- How can I see a list of changes locally that want to push to the origin or upstream?

Maybe TortoiseGit does not have those; if not: please suggest tools that do.

Comment: The free SourceTree application at least shows you the changes that need to be pushed. There are both a Windows and Mac OS X version: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't directly apply to TortoiseGit, but im sure you will find the equivalent features easily.

Git is a distributed version control system. In order to see the remotes changes, you need to fetch them first:

```
git fetch
```

Then you can use `git diff` to view the differences between your current branch, or even your current (dirty) working directory.

Alternatively you may use `git merge --dry-run` to see what has to be merged.

---

To see the things you have changed but not commited (uncommited changes) just type `git status`.

Comment: I know about these commands, but the cool thing that TortoiseHG can to is show you a kind of 'dry run' of what would be fetched. Same for what would be pushed to a certain origin/upstream. Having such lists is a wonderful addition to your workflow routine.

Answer (score 0):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) can do this: without the need to fetching, it shows I'm 1 change behind on the upstream remote.

After pulling it, it shows the origin remote is 2 changes behind on master.

[image: I'm 1 change behind on the upstream remote]
[image: Origin remote is 2 changes behind on the master]